# Are all ceiling fan switches interchangeable?

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

I need to replace the switch in a ceiling fan and the current switch's model number is "ZE-109 E89885". If I look for it at Home Depot and they don't have that exact model, what is acceptable?

[image: ZE-109]

Comment: I got a replacement switch for my 35-year-old Hunter fan at a small retail store which sells and services fans. The switch was not cheap, but went right in and has worked for several years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fairly standard.  I wouldn't worry about the precise part number.

Your man at Home Depot should be able to help you find a replacement.

Any switch that will fit the hole will work.

Answer (score 4):

Everone seems to be forgetting the switch circuitry.  A L312 (Circiut R) is not the same as a L123 (Circuit M) even though both are KTE 3089 switches.

This means the power is different if you hook them up the same.

Comment: I was surprised to find this when I had to replace a fan speed pullchain, I ended up needing a switch that did 1-2-(1+2) so I used low voltage to test the chain switch's patterns until I found one that matched. Unless the fain switch is a simple off/on, it needs to match the activation pattern of the existing switch to work with the capacitors for speed.

Comment: Was going to post exactly this warning. I've replaced a four-pull switch in one fan, and the replacement did *not* match the pinout of the original. It may indeed have been reversed order. I just figured out what the new arrangement of wires had to be, but not everyone reads schematics or checks before installing.